# Whitespace because of text inserted on top of page

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of new to using HTML/CSS for real, so this maybe a stupid question.

My problem is a persistent whitespace on top of the page. At first I thought it was something about margin or padding, as suggested by Google and StackOverflow, but as far as I can tell it was nothing of that. I narrowed it down to a piece of text that is being added right after the opening body tag.

Here's what I mean:

If my code on the file is (simplified, but this is enough to cause the effect):

`<html><body><p>text</p></body></html>`

When I open it in Chrome and use the developer tools to see the elements, it's like this:

`<html><body>""<p>text</p></body></html>`

If I delete the "" it renders flawlessly. Right now I have a couple of lines of Javascript to remove the "" from every page, but that's obviously not ideal.

Also worth of note is that if put no tags in the body, like this:

`<html><body>text</body></html>`

Then no "" is inserted.

Besides Chrome, I've tested on Firefox and IE9, same thing happens. What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have no script inserting that "" on the page?

Comment: Is this HTML hardcoded in a file? Is it dynamically generated?

Comment: I can't seem to trace the problem. Could you try and give a jsfiddle where this is prominent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. Your comments were great. I had no script, just bare HTML, but as Jon pointed out, it's dynamically generated. Once I realized what was involved (I admit I should have realized it sooner ...) it was easy to find the answer:

[Django template inheritance breaks site layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112104/django-template-inheritance-breaks-site-layout)

It's solved. Thanks again.